# Design for accessing custom log files in GKE Auto pilot cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a sprintboot application docker image deployed on a GKE Autopilot cluster. The application is using logger to capture the logs in a file and now we need to find a way to access the content of the log files and if possible need to redirect the logs to the cloud logging. Can anyone suggest any viable solution to this problem?

We were thinking to deploy a sidecar application to read the logs and emit to cloud logging but if there is any better solution to go with ?

Thanks in advance.

We have tried to look into the datadog agents but that didnt help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.

- (Easier way) Enable logging for workloads in the cluster (by going to cluster details, click the edit pencil for `Logging` row under `Features` section, and make sure that `Workloads` is checked). After enabling it for workloads, you can just redirect your logger to standard output and GKE logging agent should collect it and send it to Cloud Logging automatically.
- (Might not be possible in autopilot) You can configure it yourself as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/about-logs#custom_agents).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1. Option-1 : This is already enabled for us and the stdout is already being redirected to the cloud logging. On the other point to change the logger to standard output,  this wont work for us as the springboot application is designed to generate the logs in the files only.
2. Option-2 : Yes this is the only option we can see but we might struggle because of the limitations we have with auto pilot clusters in GKE.

Comment: Can you share more info about the logger used? Most loggers I dealt with can output to stdout. I would like to take a look.
Also do you know where does file used in spring boot for logging gets written (e.g. persistent disk?)

Regarding option 2, you are right. I am not sure if it is possible in autopilot, I've edited my answer.